# Calculating an average inside a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

i need to make a code which calculate the average inside an array.

the user inputs the size and a 2D array. for each number in this 2D array, the program should calculate the average of the numbers above and in the left of which. 
afterwards, a new array needs to be printed in which the average values will be stored instead of the number the average was calculated for.

for example- for size- 3 and the array-

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

the result will be:

```
1   1.5  2
2.5  3  3.667
4    4.5 5
```

this is what i tried so far

```
    int main()
{
    int size, i = 0,j = 0,r=0,c=0;
    double array[N][N] = {{0},{0}},sum[N][N]= {{0},{0}};
    scanf("%d",&size);
        for (i=0; i<size ;i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<size ;j++)
            {scanf("%lf",&array[i][j]);
                }}
   for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {   for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
                for(r = 0;r<i;r++)
                    {for (c = 0;c<j;c++)
                            sum[r][c] += array[i][j];

                            }

        }

        sum[r][c] =(sum[r][c])/((i+1)+(j+1));
}
    for (r=0; r<size; r++){
        for (c=0; c<size; c++)
            printf("%.2f ",sum[r][c]);
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also `3.667` might be wrong in the example. This is because `(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) / 6` is `3.5`. Unless I have made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply accumulate vertically, horizontally, and divide by the number of elements:

```
memcpy(sum, array, sizeof(sum)); // copy array into sum

for (i=1;i<size;i++) { // vertical accumulation
    for(j=0;j<size;j++) {
        sum[i][j] += sum[i - 1][j];
    }
}

for(j=1;j<size;j++) { // horizontal accumulation
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
        sum[i][j] += sum[i][j - 1];
    }

for (i=0;i<size;i++) { // divide by the number of elements
    for(j=0;j<size;j++) {
        sum[i][j] /= ((i+1)*(j+1));
    }
}
```

It is possible to reduce the number of loops, but we need to choose the right order in which we walk over the elements.

The equivalent code in MATLAB is:

```
cumsum(cumsum(array), 2) ./ cumsum(cumsum(ones(size(array, 1))), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a running sum and then count the number of elements used. Then it is easy to calculate the average.

Try something like this:

```
   double current_sum = 0;
   int current_count = 0;
   for (i=0;i<size;i++)
   {   for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            ++current_count;
            current_sum += array[i][j];
            sum[i][j] = current_sum / current_count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that calculates what the OP needs ? His averages are for all elements above/left of the current element (including the current row/column) it seems.

Comment: Agreed with Paul R, it does not work in a general case. Try putting -5 instead of 5, for example.

Comment: @ibancg, What do you mean *-5 instead of 5* ? Do you mean that the OP could input `1 2 3 4 -5 6 7 8 9` instead of `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`?

Comment: Yes, if the user inputs that, it does not work as expected.